Using properly the tutor option of polyhornerscheme from polynome package (show the steps of the horner method)
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

  \polyhornerscheme[x=2, tutor=true, tutorlimit=5, resultstyle=\color{blue}
]{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}

\end{document}

I cannot make the steps being depicted. In particular I want to get a figure similar to

(image taken from https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/polynom/polydemo.pdfThe author uses tutorlimit=3. I want to show all the steps together and not split them like the autor of polynome package demo.)
What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

The command \Showpolyhornerscheme prints the Horner's scheme for the given polynomial with respect to
the specified evaluation point while displaying all the steps together.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polynom}

%**************************************** added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{currentstage}

\newcommand\Showpolyhornerscheme[4]{%  \Showpolyhornerscheme{<total number of steps + 1}{<key=value list for \polyset>}{<evaluation point>}{<polynomial>}
    \begingroup
    \polyset{#2,tutorlimit=#1}%
    \setcounter{currentstage}{#1}\addtocounter{currentstage}{-1}%                            
    \loop \ifnum \value{currentstage}<#1\relax
    \addtocounter{currentstage}{1}%
    \[\polyhornerscheme[x=#3,stage=\value{currentstage}]{#4}\]
    \repeat
    \endgroup}
%****************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \LARGE

    \Showpolyhornerscheme{8}{tutor=true,resultstyle=\color{green}}{2}{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}
    
\end{document}

